# How can I mitigate needing to change hundreds of Google passwords?

Tags: google-chrome, security, passwords, user-accounts, automation

Google Chrome has been telling me about a security breach where passwords have been stolen from many websites and it's telling me which of my saved passwords are at risk and that I should change them. That's all good and well, but there are hundreds of them and it would take days of work to change them all manually (or delete the accounts). I made sure to change my passwords for sensitive accounts like ones that have to do with money, etc. but that's not enough for Google.

I've heard that you should always keep passwords secure even if it's a password for an account that a hacker couldn't possibly do anything harmful with. As I understand it, the reasoning behind that idea is that people reuse passwords so getting a password for a harmless account could give someone access to more serious accounts. But that's taken care of already, because all my serious accounts have unique passwords.

If it's okay to leave some unimportant accounts unsecured, is there a way to flag those passwords as "safe" so that Google won't keep bothering me to change the passwords? Alternatively, if there's some reason I haven't thought of that even low-impact accounts need to be secure than is there a way to automate the process of changing the passwords on hundreds of different websites?

Comment: Why arnt you usinng a different paaaword for each account and storing them in a passworr manager. Maybe now is the time to start?

Comment: I issued a close vote because the underlying question is about a Google Account function.

Comment: @davidgo - It sounds like you didn't read my question

Comment: @Ramhound - Where should this kind of question be asked?

Comment: @kyledelany I did. And if you were using a properly set up password manager configuration your problem of password reuse based on importance to you would not exist. Just because you deem a site unimportant does not mean a hacker will.

Comment: @KyleDelaney - Google Accounts would be within scope at Web Applications Stack Exchange.  If you agree your account is about the passwords saved to your Google Account. Google Accounts would be within scope at Web Applications Stack Exchange.  If you agree your account is about the passwords saved to your Google Account.

Comment: @davidgo - I use a different password for each account now. Your comments are extremely unhelpful.

Comment: Davidgo's comments are extremely helpful for someone reading the question you asked. It may not be the question you MEANT to ask, but evidence appears to support our understanding of what you wrote is more accurate than your own perceptions of what you wrote. You have an EDIT button at your disposal. Using it to make the question more clearly reflect your intent may save you some of this frustration you're clearing experiencing. It'll also be more respectful of those you've come asking to. We don't answer with malicious intent, and we don't misread on purpose.

Comment: @music2myear - All right, thank you for trying to help, and sorry for my frustration. In order for me to understand what needs clarification, can you paraphrase the question I'm asking as you understood it?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to all of the questions you've asked is to use a password manager.

A password manager facilitates generating and storing entirely random passwords securely, allowing for convenient but secure logins to all of your sites, zero reuse of passwords, and usually far longer passwords than you'd have a hope remembering on your own.

I will not recommend a specific product. There are plenty of good ones out there, but you'll need to make that choice yourself. Pick one that supports the devices you use, and then set an entirely new and unique (and long) password to secure it with. That one password will need to be the only password you have to remember, but it'll be securing all your other passwords, so make it a good one, and perhaps write it down and store it in a safe or something, just in case.

Choose a password manager, then begin the process of changing your passwords, all of them, and storing them in the password manager. Start with the more valuable ones such as your email account and any banking or financial accounts, but change all of them.

UPDATE:

If you don't want Google flagging the passwords, the answer is still a password manager.

However, it is an exceptionally poor choice to not change passwords just because they are "minor" or "unimportant" accounts. The information in those accounts can be compiled to make a more successful attack on your identity and your more valuable accounts.

So the answer, much as you appear not to want to hear it, is to use a real password manager, by which me mean, "not whatever you're using right now", and then changing ALL of your passwords to be random, long, and secure.

Comment: Does Google Chrome's password manager not count as a password manager? I'm not sure you comprehended my question

Comment: @KyleDelaney - When 2 highly involved community members both come up with the same conclusion about your question maybe it is more appropriate to clarify your question.   I expect that both music2myear and myself see your post as strongly implying that you used the same password in multiple places you did not care about.  I can't comment on Google Chromes password manager specifically, but if it was doing its job properly and you were using it correctly there would be no password reuse.

Comment: @davidgo - Do you actually think "You should have done this in the past" is a helpful answer for what to do in the future?

Comment: @KyleDelaney - My phrasing was forward looking - but yes - looking at the mistakes we have made in the past and working out how we should have done it  is often how we learn not to repeat them in the future.     As it appears you have also come to the conclusion that you should use different passwords for each account in future, other then you choosing to think we lack comprehension skills and/or are being unhelpful, we are in agreement on the solution here.  IMHO it would be appropriate to accept music2myear answer.

Comment: @davidgo - Does a password manager solve the problem of needing to change *existing* passwords in hundreds of *existing* accounts? Or does it just help you keep track of all the unique passwords you have once you have them?

Comment: @Kyledelaney Some password managers can be configured to automatically update passwords, although this us not a function ive ysed - and I believe its purpose is along the lines of handling sites that require password expiration.  Its designed to CREATE and manage RANDOM passwords, but there is no single password standard that can be used across all sites.  As the saying goes - an ounce if prevention is worth a pound of the cure.

Comment: @davidgo - I agree that an ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure, but it's too late for prevention. This is like me asking how to treat a burn and you answering by saying I should have been more careful like that's a useful solution to my current problem. This isn't prevention, this is hindsight.

Comment: Yes, password managers aid in changing passwords by tracking the passwords you've created with a minimum of effort. Password managers nearly all also contain password generating features that pipe directly into their default storage features. Certain password managers, also as @davidgo notes, offer automatic or semi-automatic password change features. Unlike davidgo, I've used these, and they kinda work some of the time. The point is there isn't any real "change all my passwords for me" tool, but there are tools that ease that process as much as possible, and these are password managers.

Comment: @music2myear - If I wasn't using a password manager then there would be nothing telling me that I need to change my passwords in the first place, so this is still reading to me like you're not understanding my problem. To the extent that you do understand my problem, it sounds like you're saying it can't be solved. I will accept this answer if you edit it to explicitly say that what I'm trying to do cannot be done and that all my passwords must be changed manually, and also give an explanation for why all accounts need to be secure. I don't know what a hacker is going to do with some of these.